# ReactJs - Warning when transitioning off page after successful login

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a straight foward login page which calls an api service to verify user login:

**Login.js**

```
@connect(
  state => ({user: state.auth.user}),
  authActions)
class Login extends React.Component {

  ......

  _handleSubmit = (event) => {
     .....
    this.props.login({username: username.value, password: password.value},
     (result) => {
      return result;
    });
    ......
  };

  render() {
    const {user, logout} = this.props;
    return (
      <section>
        {
          !user ?
            ... Show login page with submit button .....

            : this.context.router.replace('/')
        }
      </section>
    )
  }
};
```

While the component works as intended, I am receiving the warning:

> **Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be
>   a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an
>   anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`**

I know the warning is due to the replace state of the router, but I do not know what would be the best way to prevent this warning and still accomplish the goal of moving away from the login page if the User exists.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Abdud Dayan Adeeb had the solution .....

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps ) {
    if (nextProps.user) this.context.router.replace('/')
  }
```

Comment: the code should be placed in componentWillUnmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see here is you are trying to attempt a transition when the component is rendering/updating.

The best thing to do would be to move the transition logic to the `componenetWillReceiveProps` function of your component

```
componenentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user) this.context.router.replace('/')
}
```

Comment: componentWillMount does not get hit after submit. FYI, the submit method has a e.preventDefault()

Comment: You can still use `componentWillUpdate`. Both `componentWillUpdate` and `componentWillMount` get called before the render. `componentWillMount` only gets called before the initial render and `componentWillUpdate` gets called on each subsequent rerenders.

Comment: Since you're using redux, and if you're strictly following the one way data flow model. It's best to use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

Comment: I've updated my answer. to `componentWillReceiveProps` after your feedback.

Comment: Thanks! That did the job w/o warnings!

Comment: @SarasotaSun Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Yes, you must keep in mind that render method must be **DECLARATIVE**